# Send FCM notification to multiple devices using PHP

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Guys I'm using this PHP script to get push notification to multiple devices getting the tokens from mysql database

```
<?php 

function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = xxxxxxxxx:APA91bHLgg7fyiQDQYTNVDTYNwjSekh_aAQ9VTT6wz8erBrNbpsBHjaxq5cNaEOX4OCRWccopPiqy2eam_HN3aW71wInlsqBFuPm3fCiCFii1eIgQ6JN5cf_8jM9kGXPkCsWKiq9G7OW ',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

include_once'C:\xampp\htdocs\lar\connect.php';

$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];


$sql = " Select Token From notification_data where user_id='$user_id';";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$tokens = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tokens[] = $row["Token"];
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);

$message = array("message" => " FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION TEST MESSAGE");
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
echo $message_status;

?>
```

When I execute this I get succes response :

```
 {"multicast_id":8473985914541976829,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1638118017848408%ba338c17f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

But the my android app crushes if it is in foreground
I tried notification tests and it works fine, hope you can help

**EDIT** :
This is the firebaseMessaging class in android studio

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String CHANNEL_ID ="101" ;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "101")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the 
notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

}

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
    Log.e("TAG", "onNewToken: "+s );

}
```

}